# Is there a way to change the keyboard settings of a certain language?

Tags: language

In the Hebrew keyboard configuration, if you want to have the "n" letter (nun) on the screen, you have to press a key near the space key, which on the English keyboard is the letter "b".

Can I change that?

I would like to switch from German keyboard to Hebrew keyboard, and when I press <kbd>n</kbd> the Hebrew letter for "n" should appear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you could remap the normal keyboard layout to the way you want.

You could however install a new keyboard layout like the one you want. This layout scheme is called "Homophonic keyboard". There are a lot of places from where you could download and install it. Here is one of them:

[Installing the Hebrew KU Homophonic keyboard in Windows 7](https://egarc.ku.edu/installing-hebrew-ku-homophonic-keyboard-windows-7) - (EGARC)